# Where do external dependencies live in vanilla JS web components?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm experimenting with using web components for a project — essentially custom elements powered by attributes, ideally imported by `<link rel="import">`.

Here's the problem: I can't find conclusive guidance on where to stick any external libraries my component relies on, such as moment.js or even jQuery.

Most component examples I've seen strictly use vanilla JS. When they do use an external library, they often seem to drop them in using Bower or npm and and refer to them explicitly within the component's HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js></script>
```

These days I'm more accustomed to using webpack to bundle dependencies, so this seems a bit odd.

My question: is it considered better form to **include each component's library dependencies within the component directory**, or have a **central `node_modules` folder at the project level?** How does webpack fit into this?

Answer (score 3):

It's better to have a central `node_modules` folder at the project level. Most people use Webpack to bundle their code with their dependencies. They use `require` or `import` their modules for each component.

**a.component.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
```

**b.component.js**

```
import React from 'react'
```

**app.js**

```
import A from 'a.component.js'
import B from 'b.component.js'
```

Webpack will have one "entry": `app.js` and compile it `output`: `app.min.js`

**why?**

- It's easier to manage (update, delete, add) dependencies with `npm`.
- The browser will load one file instead of multiple external files.

**External info:**

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

https://www.quora.com/Why-use-Bower-when-there-is-npm

Comment: Makes since for ES6 modules — but what about components that also have HTML files with `<template>` code? I know webpack can handle HTML but it seems flummoxed by linking modules together via HTML imports.